# MariaDB - SELECT

Tags: mysql, select

Please, can anyone help me?

I have these tables:

ASSET

```
id   | name
1234 | server1
2345 | server2
3456 | activeYES
4567 | activeNO
5678 | new
6789 | old
```

ASSET_ASSOCIATED

```
id   | associated_id
1234 | 3456
1234 | 5678
2345 | 4567
2345 | 6789
```

How do I select the values in the `name` column that match the values 'activeYES' and 'new' in the `associated_id` column knowing that I expect to see 'server1' as the output?

Comment: Can you add the output you're trying to get for this sample? It would make the question much clearer.

Comment: Yes, of course! I am sorry! I expect to see 'server1' as the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use inner join and a in clause

```
select * from ASSET_ASSOCIATED
inner join ASSET on ASSET.id = ASSET_ASSOCIATED.associated_id
where ASSET.name in ('new', ' activeYES');
```

based on your data 
this retunr server1

```
select ASSET.name
from ASSET 
where id in ( select distinct ID from 
    from ASSET_ASSOCIATED
    inner join ASSET on ASSET.id = ASSET_ASSOCIATED.associated_id
    where ASSET.name in ('new', ' activeYES')
)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, but I ended up not putting an important data in my question, which was that I wanted to get the value 'server1' as a result.